# Enabling php sysvshm extension without recompiling

Tags: php, php-extension

I am using a shared host. PHP is compiled with `--disable-sysvshm`. I get the following error while running a script:

`Fatal error: Call to undefined function shm_attach() in ...`

Is there any way to enable it without re-compiling php?

Comment: OS?  PHP version?  Any good reason *not* to rebuild PHP, or just laziness?

Comment: About reason: OP is using shared host ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is, but as a regular user, you can't do it.  You'll need admin access.

If you have root access, then your package manager should have the extension available if it doesn't come built into PHP.  For SuSE, it's looking like a `php-sysvshm` package would do it.  If there's no package, you'll still need to rebuild, but it's doable.

If you don't have the access you'd need to build PHP or install packages, you won't be able to build or install, let alone load, extensions (which are pretty much the only way you can add functionality without replacing your existing PHP).  In that case, you'll need to talk to your web host and see if they will install it for you.  If they won't, then that's pretty much it.

Comment: Then you have access to rebuild PHP, or install an extension if it,s available via the package manager.  If you really have root access, that's not shared hosting -- it's a VPS.  :P

Comment: The problem is I don't know which extension I should install